# New to jQuery - why isn't this simple function working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm building a web application inside CodeIgniter and I've decided to have a fiddle with jQuery and Javascript - something I've never really used before.

I have included jQuery in my header using Google Libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And now I'm fiddling with the SIMPLEST of jQuery but it's not working.

```
<p><a href="#" id="lovecounter"><?php if ($post->love) { echo $post->love; } else { echo 0; } ?></a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#lovecounter").click(function() {
  alert("Click");
});         

</script>
```

I am clicking on the lovecounter link but there is no alert. If I add simple javascript to the actual anchor tag it works though.

```
<p><a href="#" id="lovecounter" onclick="alert('test')"><?php if ($post->love) { echo $post->love; } else { echo 0; } ?></a></p>
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your code in [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lovecounter").click(function() {
    alert("Click");
  });     
});
```

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/iworez)

Comment: Or even sexier: `$(function() { /* stuff to do when ready */})`

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
<p><a href="#" id="lovecounter">asdf</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#lovecounter").click(function() {
  alert("Click");
});         

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Evik. I was an idiot and forgot to ready the document!

Answer (score 0):

You should include a `$(document).ready(function() {});` just like Sarfraz said. Otherwise, it would not find anything with an id of `lovecounter` because nothing on the page has loaded yet. If you wait for it to load, then it will find the element. Here is some documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp. Here is a full jQuery lesson: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery.